# Multiple movie textures in scene (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, materials, video

I have got a scene which consists of multiple objects with different movie textures.

It seems that **only** the movie texture of the **last selected object** (not objects) **will update** in the viewport and render.

How can I get it so that all movie textures update in both the viewport and more importantly; the render, please?

PS: My image-texture settings are: Frames: 96, Start Frame: 1, Offset: 1, Cyclic (yes) Auto Refresh (yes).

I am rendering with **Cycles**.

Comment: Blender viewport does not support animated texture preview. See related https://developer.blender.org/T45714 and https://developer.blender.org/T43479 In the render they should update regularly

Comment: I've tried to answer this but it won't accept it when posted.  Basically I've just textured three 3D objects with separate movies (mp4's) and all three have motion video in the 3D viewport and render to a video file without problems, again with their motion intact.  Leave a comment and I'll try again on another PC.  The OS was W7 and Blender was 2.77.

Comment: That's really bizarre! I can't get this to work! Only the move texture of the object which I have currently previewed in the material preview view will render. I was able to work around this by creating an object with a material consisting of every movie texture in the scene. By selecting this object upon rendering, only then would all the movies update. It's important to note that I am rendering with CYCLES.

Comment: Ah, Cycles.  I didn't see that.  I saw the comment referring to Blender Viewport.  Apologies for getting your hopes up.  Video rendering takes too long for me in Cycles.  (thousands of frames would take a lifetime!)